# How to export this function in Node.js into another module

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, protractor

I am using protractor to test an Angular JS application.
I would like to use page object pattern therefor I need to export a function into another module.

Here is my page-login.js file:

```
require("./login.spec.js");
var LoginPage = function ()
{
   this.userName = element(by.id('login_form_user_input'));
   this.password =  element(by.id('login_form_password_input')) ;
   this.loginButton = element(by.id('login_form_signin_button'));
   this.loginText = element(by.css('#mainGlobalSearchBtn'));
   this.loginError = element(by.xpath('html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div/p'));
   this.login = function (userName, password)
       {
         LoginPage.userName.sendKeys(userName);
         LoginPage.password.sendKeys(password);
         LoginPage.loginButton.click ();
         browser.waitForAngular ();
       };
};

 exports.LoginPage = LoginPage;
```

Now in another js file called login.spec.js under the same folder I would like to call the login this method :

```
var util = require ('util');
require("./myconfig.js");
describe('Login', function() {
var loginPage = require("./login-page.js");
var ptor;

beforeEach (function ()
{
     ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    ptor.get(settings.winURL);
    waits(2000);
    //Delete cookies to avoid saving password or username
});
it('should not login : incorrect login details', function()
{
     loginPage.login('incorrectusername','incorrectpassword');
     expect(loginPage.loginError.getText()).toContain('Access denied');
});
```

When Launching this code protractor is not entering username and passwoed in corresponding fields and I got this console ouput :

```
   1) Login should not login : incorrect login details
   Message:
   TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'login'
   Stacktrace:
   TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'login'
   at null.<anonymous> (C:\******\login.spec.js:34:20)
```

here is line 34 that is throwing the error :

```
loginPage.login('incorrectusername','incorrectpassword');
```

How can I use the login functioninside the login page function in another module?

Answer (score 0):

The `require( './login-page.js' )` returns a "class" function. It means that, to call `login` method of `loginPage` module you might to use `new`. Ex.:

```
it('should not login : incorrect login details', function()
{
    var page = new loginPage();
    page.login('incorrectusername','incorrectpassword');
    expect(page.loginError.getText()).toContain('Access denied');
});
```

Comment: Or exports this way: exports.LoginPage = new LoginPage();

Comment: I have tried both methods and both are returning the same error as above!

Comment: Your module returns a function, but should return a instance. You are trying to access a method on a function, there is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `require("./login.spec.js");` of the begin of your module. The test is running before the module creation.

Comment: you're correct I have removed it but this is not related to my error, I guess my prblem is I am exposing a function and using another function inside it?

Answer (score 0):

Protractor has this awesome option called onPrepare. You put this in your config.js file. Your onPrepare can reference a file.

In this file you can have all the variables and functions you need!

Instead of "this" you use global.

```
global.userName = element(by.id('login_form_user_input'));
global.password =  element(by.id('login_form_password_input')) ;
global.loginButton = element(by.id('login_form_signin_button'));
global.loginText = element(by.css('#mainGlobalSearchBtn'));
global.loginError = element(by.xpath('html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div/p'));
global.login = function (user, pw)
   {
     userName.sendKeys(user);
     password.sendKeys(pw);
     loginButton.click ();
     browser.waitForAngular ();
   };
```

then in your config you do:

```
//other config settings,
onPrepare: myvariables.js
```

in your spec, you don't need to require anything!

Just call what you need (minus the global)

```
beforeEach (function () {
 ptor = protractor.getInstance();
ptor.get(settings.winURL);
waits(2000);
//Delete cookies to avoid saving password or username
});
it('should not login : incorrect login details', function()
{
   login('incorrectusername','incorrectpassword');
 expect(loginError.getText()).toContain('Access denied');
});
```

you also might want to name your userName variable and the userName arg and password different things. (fixed above)